# Radio buttons can't be checked after removing 'appearance' in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 radio buttons that are tied to a function that supposed to change an image inside a div when each button is checked. It's working ok but when I adding CSS style to it so the actual checker won't be visible to only the icons I set will show, it'makes it uncheckable.

*Note:* when I remove the `#sm-jum-btns input` CSS and the checkers actually visible the code working. I need it to work also when those checkers are hidden and designed.

HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

 <div class="jumbotron text-center" id="main-jum">
    <img id="jum-img" src = "https://im.whatshot.in/img/2017/Oct/churrosweb-1509092812.jpg">
 </div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center d-md-none" id="sm-jum-btns">
   <input id="radio_left" type="radio" name="optradio" onclick="changeImg()">
    <label id="btn-left"class="radio-inline sm-jum-btn ">
      <span class="fa fa-layers fa-fw fa-circle-thin">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </span>
    </label>

   <input id="radio_middle" type="radio" name="optradio" onclick="changeImg()">
    <label id="btn-left"class="radio-inline sm-jum-btn ">
      <span class="fa fa-layers fa-fw fa-circle-thin">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </span>
    </label>

   <input id="radio_right" type="radio" name="optradio" onclick="changeImg()">
    <label id="btn-left"class="radio-inline sm-jum-btn ">
      <span class="fa fa-layers fa-fw fa-circle-thin">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </span>
    </label>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(){
  var jumImg = document.getElementById("jum-img");
  var radioLeft = document.getElementById("radio_left");
  var radioRight = document.getElementById("radio_right");
  var radioMiddle = document.getElementById("radio_middle");

  if (radioLeft.checked){
    jumImg.src = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg";
    }
  if (radioRight.checked){
    jumImg.src = "https://images7.alphacoders.com/411/thumb-1920-411820.jpg";
    }
  if (radioMiddle.checked){
    jumImg.src = "http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-4.jpg";
    }
  }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#sm-jum-btns input {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
     -webkit-appearance:none;
     -moz-appearance:none;
      appearance:none;
      margin-top: 180px;

}

#sm-jum-btn {
  position: relative;
}

.fa-circle-thin {
  color: #ffb300;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fa-circle-thin::before {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3.5px;
  margin-top:3.5px;
}

.fa-circle {
  color: #ffb300;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius:50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.fa-circle-thin:hover {
  color: #37100B;
}

#main-jum {
  padding: 0;
}

#main-jum img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: Try hiding your `input` using `opacity:0; height:0; width:0;` instead of `appearance`

Comment: It's also hide the checkers but they still cant be checked after it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after two days of searching and asking I figure it out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706097/radio-buttons-with-font-awesome-icons-are-not-working) answer.

Basically I should add a `for` attribute in each `label` to point it to it's  parent `input id` so it can actually check the `input` and trigger the function.

more about `for` attribute you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp)